# XMPP over WebSocket for a web chat and firewalls

Tags: websocket, xmpp, firewall

I'm working on a project that involves a client that has to use a real-time chat on a website.
I also have to set up a firewall (with access lists) that doesn't let me go on another website.

So the question is, if I rely on an XMPP over WebSocket webchat, the communication with the XMPP server is made directly by the web server or it starts from me?
In other words, in the access lists should I worry about specifying the connection with the XMPP server?

Ty and sorry if it's a stupid question

Answer (score 0):

The connection from the client (run in the browser for example) makes a connection to particular hostname. It can be the same machine as your webserver (or subdomain) or another hostname (which I assume would be an issue for you if you want to limit who can connect to your server).

But nothing prevents you from handling websocket traffic on your server and for forwarding it (using proxy) to the actual XMPP server.

For example using [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)